# Genexus 15 sincronización offline BusinessComponent not found: OCLOCKIT\\Devices"}]

Tags: genexus

Tengo el siguiente problema con *Genexus 15*.

Tengo una aplicación offline en *Android*, una transacción ***Devices*** que está como **Business Component**.

A nivel del servidor tiene un registro que se sincroniza hacia el ***SmartDevice*** sin problemas. Cuando cambio algo en ese registro en el *SD*, al sincronizar da el siguiente error capturado por un *sniffer*:

> ```
> EventErrors=[{
>     "Id":"BC not found",
>     "Type":1,
>     "Description":"BusinessComponent not found: OCLOCKIT\\Devices"
> }]
> ```

La aplicación se llama ***Oclockit*** y la tabla es ***Devices***.

Lo *trn* está como *Offline* y como *WS* con protocolo *Rest*.

Comment: El Business Component "Devices" esta en modulo? (llamado OCLOCKIT?)
Que version de Genexus 15 estas utilizando?

Comment: Hola Fernando, la respuesta es sí, esta en el mismo módulo y se llama Oclockit, en el mismo lugar donde estás los BC que si funcionan, te comento que esto antes me funcionaba y dejo de hacerlo, lo que no tengo claro es en que momento se dio. Estoy con la Gx 15 U1.

Comment: Gracias por responder..

Comment: Pruebo a ver si reproduzco el problema. El server es net o java?. Te aviso si preciso xpz. Gracias

Comment: Es .net. Te cuento que Marcelo Eguiluz tiene ya un XPZ reciente por otro problema, por si te sirve de ejemplo.. ya en ese no funcionaba.

Comment: Fernando, cómo estás?  Necesitas algún aporte mas para las pruebas? ¿ Que te parece que pueda probar? Estuve intentando dejar el BC = False de esa Trn para volver a crearlo, pero no me guarda el cambio,  tal vez porque ya tenga objetos haciendo mención al BC? Gracias

Comment: Fernando, cómo estás?  sigo trancado con este tema... alguna pista que me puedas dar al respecto de porque falta el BC Devices? Gracias..

Comment: No he podido reproducir. Estoy esperando que soporte procese el caso. Mientras, puedes probar enviar registros de cualquier otro bc, en particular alguno que no este en ningún modulo a ver si ahí funciona. Saludos.

Comment: Fernando, Marcelo Eguiluz tiene un XPZ que le mande de donde pueden probar que no funciona. Los otros BC funcionan sin problema y sincronizan en ambos sentidos. Estos BC están dentro del mismo módulo, te recuerdo que el BC Devices funcionaba al principio pero en un momento dado dejo de hacerlo, pero no recuerdo en que momento paso. Gracias.